# How to convert sting to datetime format like MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime

i get the string value like 01/05/2012(MM/dd/yyyy) , now i have to convert into datetime

```
string s="01/05/2012";
datetime dt=convert.todatetime(s);
```

Now dt value is 1/5/2012, but i have to get dt value 01/05/2012, how to get the value , plese give me any idea about that.

Thanks
hemanth

Comment: The "dt" value is **not** 1/5/2012. It is a binary format that us not human readable. If you need a specific character representation, you have to convert back to string.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your `DateTime` object correctly, you are just looking at the internal representaion of the DateTime. The way that it is output depends on the Format String you give its [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) Method. 
i.e.:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "01/05/2012";
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

If you look at this MSDN Page on the [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx)

From above link highlighting mine

> DateTime Values and Their String Representations
>
> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a user interface element or when written to a file. **The appearance of a DateTime value is the result of a formatting operation.** Formatting is the process of converting a value to its string representation.
>
> Because the appearance of date and time values is dependent on such factors as culture, international standards, application requirements, and personal preference, **the DateTime structure offers a great deal of flexibility in formatting date and time values through the overloads of its ToString method.** The default DateTime.ToString() method returns the string representation of a date and time value using the current culture's short date and long time pattern.

Comment: I have to get dt as datetime datatype, you have convert string

Comment: @hmk please see edit for explanation of what I am trying to say

Comment: @hmk if you want a datetime, you don't care about format. Datetime stores in an unreadable binary format, and display format only matters when you convert to string