# C# Datetime format conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a conversion problem with datetime.  I have a date string as `MM/dd/yyyy`. Now I need to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

But I'm facing some error. Please help

```
 public static DateTime ToDBDateTime(string _dateTime)
 {
        string sysFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

        string _convertedDate = string.Empty;

        if (_dateTime != null || _dateTime != string.Empty)
        {
            _convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_dateTime, sysFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(_toDBDateFormat);
            //_convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_dateTime).ToString(_toDBDateFormat);
           /// Debug.Print(sysFormat);
        }

        return Convert.ToDateTime(_convertedDate);
    }
```

And I want to know that is there is any way to pass the `datetime` in various formats and it would return the expected format.

E.g.: if I pass date as `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`, the above function would return the date in format as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Please provide some suggestion to solve `datetime` issues.

Comment: Show us the date you are parsing?

Comment: DateTime Objects do not have a format per say they are a binary object, please look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466220/how-to-convert-sting-to-datetime-format-like-mm-dd-yyyy/13466443#13466443)

Comment: You should give some context: why are you using this function? How come the input is in string format? Also, your function is called `ToDBDateTime`, so it seems you want to use the result to insert in a database. It is not necessary to convert a DateTime object to `string` for that; use parametrized sql instead.

Comment: @jeroenh: Spot on :) I wish there were some way of just prohibiting literal values in SQL...

Answer (score 4):

> I have a date string as MM/dd/yyyy

Right... and yet you're trying to parse it like this:

```
string sysFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
...
_convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_dateTime, sysFormat,
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You need to give a format string which matches your input - so why are you including a time part? You probably just want:

```
string sysFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

However, that's not the end of the problems. You're *then* converting that `DateTime` *back* into a string like this:

```
.ToString(_toDBDateFormat)
```

... and *parsing* it once more:

```
return Convert.ToDateTime(_convertedDate);
```

Why on earth would you want to do that? You should *avoid* string conversions as far as possible. Aside from anything else, what's to say that `_toDBDateFormat` (a variable name which raises my suspicions to start with) and `Convert.ToDateTime` (which always uses the current culture for parsing) are going to be compatible?

You should:

- Work out how you want to handle being given an empty string or null, and just return an appropriate `DateTime` then
- Otherwise, just parse using the *right* format.

This part of your question also concerns me:

> E.g.: if I pass date as dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy, the above function would return the date in format as yyyy-MM-dd.

There's no such thing as "the date in format as yyyy-MM-dd". A `DateTime` is *just* a date and time value. It has no intrinsic format. You specify how you want to format it *when* you format it. However, if you're using the value for a database query, you shouldn't be converting it into a string again *anyway* - you should be using parameterized SQL, and just providing it *as* a `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes.. But i'm getting this date from a webservice  in MM/dd/yyyy format. But converting it into datetime and while inserting it into a dataset in which the column is of type Datetime. Here i'm getting a error.

Comment: @Vijay: I don't see how your comment in any way contradicts my answer: convert to a `DateTime` (using the *correct* format string) and then keep the result as a `DateTime`. That's all there is to it. If you're getting an error after doing that, you need to tell us what that error is, rather than adding pointless and problematic extra conversions.

Comment: @Joe: Sorry sir. I'll explain my problem. I have a webservice which returns a datetime value. While testing it in Visual studio, i get the date in format dd/MM/yyyy. When im hosting the webservice in IIS, i get the date in format as MM/dd/yyyy.I dont why this happens. may be due to the configuration of the IIS.  So i want to centralize the format conversion. So i'm using the above function.

Answer (score 3):

As you have a date in a string with the format "MM/dd/yyyy" and want to convert it to "yyyy-MM-dd" you could do like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Neither the input nor output format is as you describe - and I think this also ignores some more fundamental issues with the OP's assumptions.

Comment: Sorry my bad about the formats, but sir can you please explain what fundamental issues it ignores, i am pretty much new in c#

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt tostring like this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(_convertedDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") or whatever format you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working fine.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1);
date1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
```

You can apply any format in this ToString.

Hope that helps
Milind