# How convert string to Datetime by a format?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to DateTime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

How can I convert string to DateTime by a format?

```
Convert.ToDateTime("12/11/17 2:52:35 PM")
```

Result is `12/11/2017 02:52:35 PM` and this is incorrect because
my expect is `11/17/2012 02:52:35 PM`

Comment: There is no formatting involved with a DateTime object, it is a numerical value. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466220/how-to-convert-sting-to-datetime-format-like-mm-dd-yyyy/13466443#13466443

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myStr, "yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.

```
   DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(yourdatestring, 
                                        "yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt",             
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use one of the `DateTime.*Parse` methods.

These take the string representing the `DateTime`, a format string (or array of them) and some other parameters.

The [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) would be `yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt`.

So:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/11/17 2:52:35 PM", 
                               "yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [culture of the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165448.aspx):

```
// Date strings are interpreted according to the current culture. 
// If the culture is en-US, this is interpreted as "January 8, 2008",
// but if the user's computer is fr-FR, this is interpreted as "August 1, 2008" 
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);            
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

// Specify exactly how to interpret the string.
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);

// Alternate choice: If the string has been input by an end user, you might  
// want to format it according to the current culture: 
// IFormatProvider culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day {2}", dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day);

/* Output (assuming first culture is en-US and second is fr-FR):
    Year: 2008, Month: 1, Day: 8
    Year: 2008, Month: 8, Day 1
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                                "yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt",
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                DateTimeStyles.None);
```

"tt" is the AM/PM designator.

Comment: See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038.aspx)