# How to take a varchar field and compare as date in C# using RowFilter

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a field in my SQL table

```
`OurDate (varchar(250), null)`
//sample dates
//  01/18/2018
//  05/12/2016
//  03/05/2012
```

I am trying to compare the table data between two dates in that field column using `RowFilter`:

```
string fromDate = "{OurDate Sql column value from dropdown list}"; //01/18/2018
string toDate =  "{OurDate Sql column value from dropdown list}"; //01/18/2018 (could be different, if someone doesn't want same day)
dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("(CONVERT({0}, 'System.DateTime') >= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) + "# And {0} <= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(toDate) + "# )", "OurDate");
```

I get this error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Can someone please assist me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Stop treating dates as strings.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings in databases. If you have an existing database with dates stored as strings, convert them to dates in the database and use that column instead.

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many rows to change anything and I was seeing if there was a way to use it in RowFilter. Maybe it is too complicated, if so, I may have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

First you should identify what causes the Conversion issue.
Is it the `CONVERT` expression or the values used for filtering.

You can do this by splitting up your code and adding an expression column just for the conversion like this:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("TEST", typeof(DateTime), "CONVERT(OurDate, 'System.DateTime')");
```

If this line causes the error - it means that the problem is converting the data. `DataExpression`'s `CONVERT` function should be based on the `dataTable.Locale` `(which defaults to CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` property.
If your data is indeed always in "MM/dd/yyyy" format setting this to

```
dataTable.Locale = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Should solve the problem - **If the data in the table is in an inconsistent format - you will not be able to solve this using RowFilter/DataExpressions**

At this point you will notice that your second filter condition is missing the CONVERT entirely.

In fact this entire convert step is *superficial* if all of your data is in the correct format - if `RowFilter` detects its correct format for datetime - it will apply this conversion automatically to your column.

That being said `.RowFilter` only accepts dates in the following formats
American *"MM/dd/yyyy"* and *"yyyy/MM/dd"* (which I guess is considered Invariant here?)

If your local format is not one of these calling `Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)` will cause a failure to convert.
Since your strings are already in one of the accepted formats - calling this should just be a pointless round trip anyway.

TL;DR: assuming all your formats are correct  this should work:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"OurDate >= #{fromDate}# And OurDate <= #{toDate}#";
```

If your rows have different formats you'll need something with more control - I'd recommend *LINQ to DataSet* as the easiest way out since you'll be able to return `DataViews`/`DataTables` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of ConvertTo:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myStr, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I found it here [How convert string to Datetime by a format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103970/how-convert-string-to-datetime-by-a-format?lq=1) and changed the syntax a little to fit your db values' format.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use like that;

i think this way more readable more than rowfilter;

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string givenDateString = "01/26/2018";

        DateTime convertedDateFromString = new DateTime();
        DateTime.TryParse(givenDateString, out convertedDateFromString);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("OurDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

        DataRow dR = dt.NewRow();
        dR["OurDate"] = DateTime.Now;

        dt.Rows.Add(dR);

        //way 1
        var result = from d in dt.AsEnumerable().ToList()
                     where d.Field<DateTime>("OurDate").Date == convertedDateFromString.Date
                     select d;

        Console.WriteLine(result.FirstOrDefault()["OurDate"].ToString());

        //way 2
        var result2 = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where d.Field<DateTime>("OurDate").Date == convertedDateFromString.Date
                      select d;
        //result.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>[""];
        Console.WriteLine(result2.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>()["OurDate"].ToString());

    }
```