# Convert a string has datetime to DateTime

Tags: c#

I want to convert a **string of date and time** to **DateTime** structure, but it is giving this error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("5/15/2018 11:54:18 AM");       
string date= dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

I'm reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/) but I can't solve this code. What is my mistake?

What is the difference between `Convert.ToDateTime`and `DateTime.ParseExact()` in C#?

Comment: I would suggest using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`, specifying the *exact* format of your input.

Comment: What @DaisyShipton said about parsing, but note that your variable names doesn't line up with your intent, you're doing `.ToString("HH:mm")` which is minutes and seconds, but you're naming the variable `date`, this is a recipe for disaster later as you're quick to forget that your code doesn't do what it seems to be doing. You should strive to write proper names that accurately represent the content and intent of the values they hold.

Comment: Always use `DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, although this format is common enough where `TryParse()` would likely be enough

Comment: I was able to run your piece of code with no errors, can you provide more details on the type of environment you are working on (ex: .net framework version, OS, etc...)

Comment: @Adi I'm using .net framework 4.5

Comment: `TryParseExact` is the way to be sure, but probably what is happening is that your current culture settings is expecting day/month rather than month/day

Comment: Hope this link will helps you [Converting a string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: The question you quoted and comments here tell you to use `DateTime.ParseExact`, so why didn't you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How convert string to Datetime by a format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103970/how-convert-string-to-datetime-by-a-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime " format dd/MM/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on all the comments, here's how your code should look like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("05/15/2018 11:54:18 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string date = dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is my mistake?

You Mistake is You are Providing argument Convert.ToDateTime() in a wrong Format.
try Providing "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" according to Your system date Time Format .Else you need to use TryParseExatct with Specifying Format

Comment: What's wrong with the format? It works fine for me as it is in the example (I'm in `en-US` culture)

Comment: Okay.Provide Time in 24HR Format.Are you still getting Exception ?

Comment: I'm not getting an exception. Are *you* getting an exception? Does your suggestion work for you?

Comment: Okay.Something weird I found .I changed my system timezone as well as date format and the code worked .How is it possible?

Comment: The code as posted in the question will work for cultures that expect MM/dd , but will fail if the culture expects dd/MM(because there aren't 15 months). That may be it?