# datetime format of datetime.now function is showing different datetime format from system datettime format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a `ASP.NET & C#` application residing in an `windows server` with `windows server 2008 R2` Operating System, the server I am using is a `VM`. I changed my windows datetime format to `"en-US"` and my SQL server datetime format, regional settings datetime format is showing as `"MM/dd/yyyy"` but withing my .NET application developed with c# is showing datetime format of `DateTime.Now` as `"dd/MM/yyyy"` in debug mode so i can't save the data to SQL database, it is throwing exception `"invalid datetime format"`. I will be highly obliged if anybody can help me with the idea how to change the datetime format of DatetTime.Now within my application.

Here is the code snippet - 
calling section -

```
saveCustomerInfo.saveInfo(txtCustomerId.Text, userNmae, objProperties.ProposalNumber.ToString(), "", "", Total_Amount, SERVICE_TAX, STAMP_DUTY, AgentID, DateTime.Now, null, null, "", "", "", product_code, MODE)
```

called function signature is -

```
public void saveInfo(string CustomerID, string UserName, string ProposalNo, string PaymentID, string PolicyNumber, int amount, double serviceTax, double stampduty, string Agent_ID, DateTime? ProposalDate, DateTime? PaymentDate, DateTime? PolicyDate, string ClaimNo, string ClaimAmount, string ClaimStatus, int ProductCode, string mode)
```

The sql Code section is:

```
public void saveInfo(string CustomerID, string UserName, string ProposalNo, string PaymentID, string PolicyNumber, int amount, double serviceTax, double stampduty, string Agent_ID, DateTime? ProposalDate, DateTime? PaymentDate, DateTime? PolicyDate, string ClaimNo, string ClaimAmount, string ClaimStatus, int ProductCode, string mode)
    {
        string connection = SetConnectionString(SPContext.Current.Site);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select count(ProposalNo) from [aspnetdb].[dbo].[user_info_log] where ProposalNo = '" + ProposalNo + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        Int32 count = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (count == 0)
        {
            //string strFormattedProposalDate = ProposalDate.ToString().Split('/')[1] + "/" + ProposalDate.ToString().Split('/')[0] + "/" + ProposalDate.ToString().Split('/')[2];

            com.Dispose();
            com = new SqlCommand("insert into user_info_log(CustomerID,UserName,ProposalNo,PaymentID,PolicyNo,TotalAmount,ServiceTax,Stampduty,Agent_ID,ProposalDate,PaymentDate,PolicyDate,ClaimNumber,ClaimAmount,ClaimStatus,ProductCode,Mode) VALUES('" + CustomerID + "','" + UserName + "','" + ProposalNo + "','" + PaymentID + "','" + PolicyNumber + "','" + amount + "','" + serviceTax + "','" + stampduty + "','" + Agent_ID + "','" + ProposalDate + "','" + System.DBNull.Value + "','" + System.DBNull.Value + "','" + ClaimNo + "','" + ClaimAmount + "','" + ClaimStatus + "','" + ProductCode + "','" + mode + "')", con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
        com.Dispose();
    }
```

The error code is:
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue if you're using prepared statements instead.  Otherwise, you can use the overload of `ToString` on the `DateTime` object to specify the format you want.

Comment: What is datatype for ur sql table of date ????????

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your quick reply. Is there any other way if I don't want to convert the DateTime object with ToString, like any registry edit or culture info settings etc etc. Please suggest me.

Comment: Hi Chetan Sanghani, thanks for the reply. its "datetime" in sql table

Comment: A DateTime object is just a large number that doesn't have a set format. See my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466220/how-to-convert-sting-to-datetime-format-like-mm-dd-yyyy/13466443#13466443)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change culture, used in your application. Add this to the `system.web` section of web.config: `<globalization culture="en-US" />`
And also, if you don't want to change default culture for all application, you can pass en-US culture to `DateTime.ToString` method: `var str = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`

Besides all above, it's absolutely wrong approach to sending DateTime value to database as string. Consider to use parameters in your sql command: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06
This way you don't converting DateTime to string

Comment: Thanks Yuriy for your response. I have already set the "globalization" tag in web.config but failed to get any satisfactory result. I am not converting datetime object to string atall, I am sending the DateTime.Now as it is in the sql query.

Comment: function calling-"saveCustomerInfo.saveInfo(txtCustomerId.Text, userNmae, objProperties.ProposalNumber.ToString(), "", "", Total_Amount, SERVICE_TAX, STAMP_DUTY, AgentID, DateTime.Now, null, null, "", "", "", product_code, MODE)" & called function signature is - "public void saveInfo(string CustomerID, string UserName, string ProposalNo, string PaymentID, string PolicyNumber, int amount, double serviceTax, double stampduty, string Agent_ID, DateTime? ProposalDate, DateTime? PaymentDate, DateTime? PolicyDate, string ClaimNo, string ClaimAmount, string ClaimStatus, int ProductCode, string mode)"

Comment: @PinakiKaruri Yuriy ment that you should edit your question with the code you use to perform the insert into the database. It's hard to read code as a comment.

Comment: Dear Koen, sorry I misunderstood what Yuriy said. I have edited the question & included the code snippet.

Comment: @PinakiKaruri r u really expecting that by method signature anybody can realize how it working? Show code where query to database composed.

Comment: @PinakiKaruri check this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html and don't concatenate sql queries anymore

Comment: @Yuiry, can you please tell me what could be the reason that datetime.now of my application only is showing "dd/MM/yyyy" format while system datetime format is set to "MM/dd/yyyy" format even SQL server database date format is "MM/dd/yyyy", so query i mentioned earlier is saving data if i change the date format of datetime.now into "MM/dd/yyyy" format during runtime. My application is running in a virtual server and it was running fine before the physical server restart, due to some reason physical server has to be restarted as well as virtual server, from then it's behaving like this

Answer (score 0):

then try

```
this.TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

or thry this......

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("05/15/2012 10:09:28.650",
                                format,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Dear Chetan, wherever I have mentioned datetime.now within my application, it is throwing exception within my application during debug. I am really confused.

Comment: I tried it but when i passed  datetime.now tostring() in ParseExact(), its throwing exceptions